# Can't bind ObservableCollection to Combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sivm:Locator x:Key="viewModelLocator" ModelType="{x:Type ViewModels:RateVSConcentrationViewModel}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="ViewModel" Source="{StaticResource viewModelLocator}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

...

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Chambers}" > <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChamber}">-->
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChamberName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

`Chambers` is an `ObservableCollection` of objects that contains a property called `ChamberName` which I want displayed in the combobox.

In the ViewModel I have the following code:

```
foreach (var chamber in chambers)
{
     Chambers.Add(chamber);
}
OnPropertyChanged(() => Chambers);
```

But when this code executes the combobox is not updated. I have used this way to do a lot of databinding but I can't get this to work.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: can you check if there are any binding errors in the output window when you execute you code

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the relativesource on your textblock, try modifying the binding on the Text property of your textblock to the following:

```
{Binding DataContext.ChamberName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}
```

And as nit said above, always check for binding errors, they will put you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the property binding as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewModel.Chambers, Source={StaticResource viewModelLocator}}" >
```

Comment: I have tried this and what I love my monkey said. It doesnt seem to help. And i get no binding errors in the output. I can see that a property called DisplayMemberPath exists - should i use that one instead of a datatemplate with a textblock?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work doing this:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="ChamberName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Chambers}"> <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChamber}">-->
```